# git merge and keep history from original repo

Tags: git, merge

Originally we only had access to a zip of the source code.

So we downloaded, unzipped, created a git repo and pushed.

So there wasn't any git history except from our initial commit.

Now we have access to the original repo so would like to merge and upgrade.

Here is what I have done so far

Add the original repo

```
git remote add upstream url_to_their_repo
git fetch upstream
```

Create a blank branch

```
git checkout --orphan upgrade
git rm -rf .
```

Merge their code into the upgrade branch

```
git merge upstream/theirbranch
```

Copy our code on top

```
git merge master
```

It shows a few conflicts which need to be resolved but when I do

```
git blame filename
```

It shows the developer who did our initial commit rather than the original repo history.

Is there a way to just copy the history for changes we have made?

Answer (score 0):

I would rebase my changes on top of the new repository

```
                    upstream/master
                    |
                    V
A---B---C---D---E---F

G---H---I
        ^
        |
        master
```

First create a local branch from `upstream/master`

```
git branch upstreamMaster upstream/master
```

Then rebase your changes onto `upstreamMaster`, but omit your first commit. Since the first commit contains all files (unzipped project was committed) it will lead to conflicts. Furthermore you only need your changes so start at commit `H`.

```
git rebase --onto upstreamMaster H master
```

You can use

```
git log --pretty=format:%H master |tail -1
```

to find the first commit of master.

After the rebase your repository will look like this

```
                    upstream/master
                    |
                    V
A---B---C---D---E---F---H---I
                    ^       ^
                    |       |
       upstreamMaster       master
```

Now you can fast forward the `upstreamMaster`

```
git checkout upstreamMaster
git merge master
```

Comment: Thanks Rene, I tried this but it looks like there have been upgrades since the original commit. Eg the first zip was version 2.2, then another zip version 2.4 was downloaded and merged etc. If I have the original 2.4 version from their repo, and our version which is already at 2.4 - can I create and apply a diff patch with just our changes and history?